# The content is added and showed in the browser but jQuery can't see it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a [WebMethod] that load an html snippet and add some content to it. That [WebMethod] is then injected into a page using $.post() and .html().

A piece of snippet:

```
<p id="name"></p>
```

The [WebMethod] add content to it:

```
<p id="name">Joe</p>
```

The snippet also contains a JavaScript code, like:

```
alert($("#id").text())
```

The problem: $("#id").text() return nothing (like in the snippet) but the content ("Joe") is showed correctly in the browser. Where is the problem?

Thanks and sorry for my EngRish.

Answer (score 4):

Your element does not have an id of "id", it has an id of "name".  Change your selector to this...

```
$("#name")
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call `$("p#name")` instead of `$("#id");`

```
<p id="something"> </p>
$("p#something")...

<p class="something_else"></p>
$("p.something_else")...
```